# Check internet availability even if device is connected to Wifi or mobileData

Tags: ios, swift

How can, I check internet connectivity.?

The below code just shows the connection to wifi or mobile network but cannot check current internet connectivity.

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Comment: Use Reacability. its very easy to use.

Comment: Are you using Alamofire in your project?

Comment: Hello @TaimoorSuleman please provide exact example.

Comment: Yes @FaysalAhmed using alamofire.

Comment: Then just use this `struct Connectivity {
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkReachabilityManager()!
    static var isConnectedToInternet:Bool {
        return self.sharedInstance.isReachable
    }
}`

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, Please understand the question and check the code you have provided. **PLEASE**

Comment: Using this way I figure out the internet is available or not using Alamofire.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed it's not working brother.

Answer (score 0):

An exact answer is here [Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift). All cool developers use this solution. You also can find an example and try handle it on your own (with your base url, design of your beheviour and etc).

Comment: Please let me provide the code example @Agisight

Answer (score 0):

create a function like

```
public func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
    }
}) else {
    return false
}
var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
    return false
}
if flags.isEmpty {
    return false
}

let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

then use it as boolean value

> e.g if isConnectednetwork {}

hope this will solve you problems.

Comment: Use `Reachability`.

Comment: Nope, it is not checking the internet availability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code for check network reachability.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VzH_ysuOaXts7c6KKXzgGDLOHkV6_8QR?usp=sharing

hope! this help you...

Comment: Brother not working perfectly.please check and revert.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Reachability.h](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/blob/master/Reachability.h) and [Reachability.m](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/blob/master/Reachability.m) files in your swift project.

[image]

Create Bridging_Header

```
#ifndef xxx_Bridging_Header_h
#define xxx_Bridging_Header_h

#import "Reachability.h"

#endif /* xxx_Bridging_Header_h */
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var isReachable: Reachability!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.isReachable = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.reachabilityChanged,
                                               object: nil)
        self.isReachable!.startNotifier()
        return true
    }

    //Reachbality Notification Response
    @objc func reachabilityChanged(_ notification: Notification) {

        if self.isReachable.isReachableViaWiFi() || self.isReachable.isReachableViaWWAN() {
            print("Service avalaible!!!")
        } else {
            print("No service avalaible!!!")
        }
    }
}
```

Constants.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Constants: NSObject {

    struct ReferenecVariables {
        static let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
}
```

Viewcontroller.swift

```
...

@IBAction func loginButtonClicked() {
   if Constants.ReferenecVariables.appDelegate.isReachable.isReachable() {
      //network available
   }else {
      //network not available.
  }
}
...
```

---

---

### Or Another Answer

---

Add SystemConfiguration.framework
[image]

```
import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration
....
....
@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(sender:AnyObject){
    let status:Bool = self.checkInternet()
    if status == false {
       //Network not available
    }else{
       // Network available
    }
}
func checkInternet() -> Bool{
    //CHECK INTERNET CONNECTION
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }
    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

    return isReachable && !(needsConnection)
}
```

Comment: Your code is only checking the connection to wifi not checking Internet Availability.

Comment: I have integrated what you provide and just check.

Comment: Sorry, @Ramprasath Selvam it's now working. It's only checking the connection with wifi or mobile data. Not checking if it has **an internet connection or not?**

Answer (score 0):

Use Alamofire library to check the device connected to the network or not.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class Connectivity {
    class func isConnectedToInternet() ->Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}
```

And add this to your code

```
if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
        print("Yes! internet is available.")
        // do some tasks..
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Reachability framework to check internet connection, here is my manager

```
import UIKit
import Reachability

class ReachabilityManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = ReachabilityManager()
    var reachabilityStatus: Reachability.Connection = .none
    let reachability = Reachability()

    var isNetworkAvailable: Bool {
        return reachabilityStatus != .none
    }

    @objc func reachabilityChanged(notification: Notification) {
        guard let reachability = notification.object as? Reachability
            else {
                return
        }
        reachabilityStatus = reachability.connection
        switch reachability.connection {
        case .none:
            NoInternetView.show()
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reachable, object: nil, userInfo: ["connected": false])
        case .wifi, .cellular:
            NoInternetView.hide()
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reachable, object: nil, userInfo: ["connected": true])
        }
    }

    func startMonitoring() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
        do {
            try reachability?.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Could not start reachability notifier")
        }
    }

    func stopMonitoring() {
        reachability?.stopNotifier()
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    }

}
```

in `AppDelegate` call `ReachabilityManager.shared.startMonitoring()`

Comment: Please provide the full code

Comment: install ReachabilitySwift with cocoapods, this class will notificate about connection changes all controllers subscribed for .reachable(custom notification name) via NotificationCenter

Comment: Did that but not work. It would be batter if you provide full code here or in the link.

Comment: it's full code, remove parts you don't need, What are the problems using it?

Comment: Please provide the link for **ReachabilitySwift**

Comment: Not working with Swift > 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I check the answers many of them done with libraries, it is not so hard without library, my answer is for anyone who want to check their status without using library.

First define this function:

```
let monitor = NWPathMonitor()

  func checkConnetionStatus() -> Bool {
        var status  = Bool()
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { pathUpdateHandler in
            if pathUpdateHandler.status == .satisfied {
                print("Internet connection is on.")
                status = true
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Connection problem", message: "check your connection please", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.appDelegate.window.self
                alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: (self.appDelegate.window?.center.x)!, y: (self.appDelegate.window?.center.y)!, width: 0, height: 0)
                alert.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
                self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("There's no internet connection.")
                status = false
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        return status
    }
```

Then call it inside where you make request or wherever you want:

```
  func datarequest() {
          if checkConnetionStatus() == true {
            // do your job here
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is **monitor**  here?. Please provide the perfect example.

Comment: sorry for that adding what it is :)

Comment: We also need to take care of below iOS 12